# Removing "Configure in: Extensions Settings" from Quick Actions on Touch Bar in OS Sonoma 14.1

Tags: touch-bar, sonoma

I recently updated my MacBook to OS Sonoma 14.1 and noticed a change in the Touch Bar under "Quick Actions", where it now displays "Configure in: Extensions Settings". Previously, this area was blank, which I prefer as I enjoy having a black Touch Bar. However, I do use an additional Touch Bar setup as "Show Expanded Control Strip" and i want to stay when i press 'fn' button, i need only to get rid of one side of touch bar.

I wish to have the "Quick Actions" section completely black again, akin to how it was in OS Ventura. How can I achieve this?

MacBook Pro 16-inch, 2019

- Processor: 2.6 GHz 6-Core Intel Core i7
- Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5300M 4 GB
- Memory: 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
- macOS: Sonoma 14.1

This is how my problem looks:
[image]

My curent settings for touch bar (on Os Ventura this settings were blank):
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After logging in, run the following from a terminal. It'll prompt for your password.

```bash
sudo killall -9 TouchBarServer
```

After running this command, the touch bar will be blank and pressing the Fn key will bring up the extended control strip as it did in Ventura.  You only need to do this once per reboot.

It's certainly possible to make this into a fancy Login Item so you never need to run commands manually but I don't reboot my computer enough to care.

Comment: its working, how can i automate it? after reloading pc?

Comment: i need this to work, automatic, this is actually what i need, but i want it to stay after i reload pc. I have 23 hours to give you bounty :)
need automated solution

Comment: i gave you bounty, because it was last hour, but your answer doesn't solve problem completely, can you update it?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Change Touch bar shows to App Controls

Comment: App controls show different stuff, for example in safari it may show one thing, in chrome smiles while im typing right now this text, and in other programs it shows different settings, so it doesn't work. I want ```blank``` (black) touch bar ```at all time```